# My button is not working, i click on him but he does nothing. He was supposed to start listening to the user's voice. I'm using java on android studio

Tags: java, android-studio, speech-recognition, onclicklistener, floating-action-button

The instance

```
FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
```

here he was supposed to start listening
to the user

```
fab.setOnClickListener((view) -> {
    Intent intent = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);
    intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL,
        RecognizerIntent.LANGUAGE_MODEL_FREE_FORM);
        intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_MAX_RESULTS, 1);
    meuRv.startListening(intent);
});

initializeTextToSpeech();
initializeSpeechRecognizer();
}
```

//the button on the xml is here

```
<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton

  android:id="@+id/fab"

  android:layout_width="wrap_content"

  android:layout_height="wrap_content"

  android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"

  android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"

  app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_mic_black_24dp"

  android:tint="@android:color/white"/>
```

I already have the record audio permission activated, but still...

Comment: Please give a full [MCVE] in your question. Explain what programming language you are using.

Comment: Done mate, it's my first question here

Comment: I still don't exactly guess what programming language you are using. Please tag your question appropriately.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch done

Comment: there is a mistake in your code somewhere.  If you include the entire MainActivity, then people can help you find it.

Comment: This is still not an [MCVE]. You need a `main`

Answer (score 1):

Do you give the permission in the manifest?
if not use this below code:

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO"
 tools:node="remove"/>

 <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.microphone" android:required="true" />
```

for more info
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/speech/SpeechRecognizer

Comment: just add the microphone feature, your button will work fine... @FelipeTeixeira